# Assign smaller 2d array to larger 2d array by reference

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, reference

In java aren't array values stored sequentially in memory?  Is there some way to assign the memory address of an array to another variable?

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String[][] board = new String[15][27];
    String[][] X     = new String[5][9];
    String[][] Y     = new String[5][9];

    X[1][3] = "X";
    X[1][5] = "X";
    X[2][4] = "X";
    X[3][3] = "X";
    X[3][5] = "X";

    Y[1][3] = "O";
    Y[1][4] = "O";
    Y[1][5] = "O";
    Y[2][3] = "O";
    Y[2][5] = "O";
    Y[3][3] = "O";
    Y[3][4] = "O";
    Y[3][5] = "O";

    board = X;

    System.out.println("\u000C");

    for (int i = 0;i < 15;i++){
        for (int j = 0;j < 27; j++){
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

Obviously the line

> board = x

doesn't work. But is there a way to assign the address of the smaller array to some part of the larger array or do we have to do this element by element?

Comment: You can make your own function for this quite easily. I doubt there is a function for this already in the default library.

Comment: a function to assign element by element or a function to assign the reference?

Comment: Element by element. What would *"assign the reference"* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you CAN assign the memory address to another variable, it will just be another reference to the same array. If you want to move the data to the larger array you have to copy them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        board[i][j] = X[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show how to assign memory address to another variable in Java?

Comment: @DCR Here is an easy guide to help you undestand: http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-assigning-object-reference/

Comment: Thanks  for the reference.  It's a little basic.  Is there a way to declare a 9X9 array and then assign the address of a 3X3 array to different segments of the 9X9?

Comment: @DCR No, you can only assign references to each row individually (1x9 arrays). You CANNOT assign a reference to a smaller 3x3 array inside a 9x9. You have to create a different array and copy the part you want.